# Linear Regression with part of pandas dataframe for 300 columns

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I have a pandas dataframe with the heat production of 300 devices mapped on the outside tempearture which looks like this:

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYQCb.png)

I now want to do a linear regression (y= ß0+ ß1*x1) on all 300 heatig_devices for the temperature range 2 to 3.5. So that x is the outside temperature and y is the heating_device output
And at the end I would like to have for every heating device a regression cefficient ß1.
Whats the best way to do so ?

Comment: Try  numpy.polyfit() [link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html)

Comment: Does any of the answers answer your question? Please mark as is :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply compute the coefficient for every column using `LinearRegression` from `sklearn.linear_model`.

```
for i in range(300):
    t = LinearRegression().fit(df[['outside temperature']], df[['heating_device'+str(i+1)]])
    print(i + 1, t.coef_[0], t.intercept_[0])
```

Now it will print the coefficient for every column

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your answer ! It gives a error back:
print(i + 1, t.coef_[0][0])
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable. I think with  t.coef_[0] its fine. But do you know how to get the other coefficient ß0 ?

Comment: Run it for one column and see what `t.coef_` returns, perhaps you just need `t.coef_[0]`

Comment: For the intercept you can use `t.intercept_`, see [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)

Comment: @ocram113 does it work for you?

Comment: I think you just mixed up x and y in .fit(...) , but apart from this it works now fine ! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Ah my bad! I will edit my answer, could you accept it? :D

Answer (score 0):

You should provide some workable code but from the numpy [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html):

```
x = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,  4.0,  5.0])
y = np.array([0.0, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, -0.8, -1.0])
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1) #1 is the fitting order i.e. degree of polynomial
z
```

For the linear case you would get two parameters `slope` and `intercept`.

If you read the docs then `y` can be a 2D numpy array. In your case `y` would be the heating values and `x` would be the temperature.